# How can I have a shortcut search for text in a note?

Tags: shortcuts-app

Lets say I have a note with 3 letters (A, B, C.). I want to make a shortcut to do something if the passed note contains "B" for example. So I need to figure out how Shortcuts finds "B" in my note.

How can I accomplish this?

PS: I tried with "Match Text/Pattern" but don't know which pattern to use.

```
Note
(A, B, C.)
|
***Match Text
Pattern: 0-9a-zA-Z***
|
If
  (INPUT) - (Contains)
  (Value: B)
  |
  Show Result:
  This Works.
otherwise
  |
  Show Result:
  This does NOT Work.
End IF.
```

Comment: You have posted the question before and received some feedback which unfortunately you didn't include neither in the original question (so it could have been reopened) nor in the repost here.

Comment: I *tried* to edit it into something I *think* you are asking. Please correct any mistakes I made.

Comment: @nohillside This is exactly what i am asking, i do not need to edit anything, thank you.

Comment: After reading your comment beneath the answer I'm not so sure about this myself. What would be the starting point/input for the shortcut you are looking for? Do you want to invoke it on a specific note? Or do you want to have a shortcut which searches *through all notes* to look for some text (the "B")?

Comment: I want it to find text in a Specific note.

Comment: How will the shortcut know for which text it should search?

Comment: Search Note (Note does contain A though) & IF Input contains Value A, then it passes, otherwise it fails.

Comment: So what is wrong with @DaniilManokhin's answer? Invoke it on a specific note (which will be the input for the search), then the shortcut asks for a search term, enter A there and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure I totally understood what you are looking for. So let me propose a solution below. If it doesn't work for your problem, please comment specifically on the proposed solution and explain where it doesn't meet your needs.

---

## The shortcut

[image]

## Its configuration

Make it accept text so we can pass Notes as input

[image]

## Let's put it to work

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This does answer my question (sort of), this is what i am looking for, but the shortcut is inside Shortcuts and NOT inside Notes.

Comment: @chris not sure I understand this. Shortcuts always are within Shortcuts (the app), they can just be triggered through the share sheet of any app (like Notes here). Maybe you can add a bit more context about what you want to accomplish overall (which real life problem you want to solve) to your question, without already assuming the solution is a Notes shortcut.

Comment: Hopefully this helps, I have a Note with A, B, C. I want my shortcut to view a Specific Note, and see if it has those A, B, C. Then if it finds one of those letters, it passes through to the next action, otherwise I want it to give an Error.

Comment: Also, I want to be inside the Shortcuts App but have it do what you did above without having to open it inside of Notes.

Comment: @Chris Don’t think this is possible, shortcuts ain’t apps. What isnthe real world scenario you are trying to solve here (the actual goal)?

Comment: I don't have a specific goal, i was going to experiment with some of the things i can do and see if this kind of thing is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as iOS can not retrieve the content of a note. This can be achieved with a third-party application like Ever Note.

Comment: But this is finding text from an "Ask For Input", i want it to find text from a "Note".

Comment: For example, I have a note that has "A" with a few other letters. I want my shortcut to find "A" in the note, and if it finds it, it passes, and if it doesn't find it, it gives an error.

Comment: @Chris Edited post